# How to create test.com with ELB in route 53

Tags: amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I created a Route53 CNAME that points to the DNS of the elastic load balancer.  Yeah! I get www.test.com. But boo!, I don't get test.com.

What how do I deal with this? The docs are terrible on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for here is called a "zone apex" record. You would like both `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` to point to your `my-elb-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.` address. Here is how to do that:

Since your WWW record is a CNAME pointed properly, you can leave it as-is. Or you can also use the method below to map it using aliases as well.

For your zone apex, the "naked" domain record, you should

1. Either create a new record set or edit the existing zone apex record for your domain.
2. Nothing should be in the "name" area of this record. (So that it is simply `domain.com`).
3. Next, you can leave the "type" as an A record, but below that, select YES for the "Alias" setting.
4. In the "Alias Target" setting, enter the full DNS value for your ELB. It should have a trailing dot at the end. Usually when you click in this field, it will give you a drop-down list of all your ELB's automatically, to make things easier.
5. Save your record set, wait a few minutes for propagation, and you should be all set.

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136293/ec2-route53-how-do-i-point-apex-record-at-load-balancer) also addresses yours.

Answer (score -1):

At the end of this article, I outlined the steps how to do it:
http://hanoian.com/content/index.php/21-aws-setup-elb-and-route53-to-handle-ssl-certificate-and-www

1 - Create a CNAME Record Set with www.example.com, value is ELB's DNS.

2 - Create a A Record Set with example.com, Alias set to Yes, value is full name of ELB's DNS.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)